# What does this warning mean? "not declared in __all__"

Tags: python

Pycharm is giving me a warning that I don't know how to fix.

[image]

So what is the wrong practice that I engaged in when coding? how can I fix this?

Comment: the module doesn’t export that object publicly.

Comment: @xrisk what do you mean? this particular line is something that I grabbed from official tutorial of that package

Comment: it’s alright then, you can ignore this error. all this means is that if you do `from pydmd import *`, `DMD` won’t be imported. by convention, packages will put a list of their “public” objects into `__all__`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#public-and-internal-interfaces) standard says

> Any backwards compatibility guarantees apply only to public interfaces. Accordingly, it is important that users be able to clearly distinguish between public and internal interfaces.

That is why IDE PyCharm warns you from import non public interfaces.

If you happen to import all Ex:`from pydmd import *`( bad practice [source](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package)) and you might get exception on accessing DMD although it was accessible - [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64130/9592801).

Comment: Thanks. Ironically though, this import line is straight from the docs of that package!!